# piping make test output to disk using python

Tags: python, makefile

I am trying to dump output of `make test` out to a text file instead of dumping in terminal shell using
`_subprocess.Popen(['make', 'test', '> & ', saveTo], shell=True,
            stdout=_subprocess.PIPE, stderr=_subprocess.PIPE, cwd=_os.getcwd())`
where `saveTo = "/username/Desktop/maketest.txt"`
but it is not working, any help would be appreciated.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
saveTo = open("/username/Desktop/maketest.txt", "w")
p = subprocess.Popen("make test", shell=True, stdout=saveTo )
ret_code = p.wait()
saveTo.flush()
```

**Not** ['make', 'test'], **but** "make test"

Comment: I was using `&` after `>` for a reason so the second process also an continue dumping in the same file, but in your case if the second process starts that is also part of  make test instead of dumping it to text file it continues to dump the later in shell.

Comment: @san For continue dumping in background you can just do not call **p.wait()**.

Comment: @san Also, if you want execute task in background you should use `&` after output file, like `make test > out.txt &`

Comment: @san Try disable buffering file: `saveTo = open("/username/Desktop/maketest.txt", "w", 0)`